# How to Implement Atomicity Manually in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

Atomicity in MySQL Databases comes with the ACID properties. I know that atomicity can be achieved using transactions, commit, and rollback.

But, if we are to do this manually (without using transactions), what would be the correct way? I came up with the following two options. Please do mention whether these are applicable, and other possible approaches.

**Option 1:** For every SQL statement, have a reverse SQL statement, so that changes can be reversed.

*Original statement:*

```
INSERT INTO table ('id', 'subject') VALUES ('00000' , 'database')
```

*Reverse Statement:*

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE 'id' = '00000'
```

**Option 2:** Create a clone of the database, update the clone, and merge it with the original database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct way is to do it with transactions. Whatever you're doing here seems like alchemy.

Comment: Neither of these methods will achieve atomicity. I think you don't really understand what "atomicity" really means.

Comment: This why transactions are built into most databases, because it's practically impossible to graft them on top.

Comment: This was a question asked at an interview. May be they were expecting something more creative? Couldn't possibly think of a better way than the  suggested two methods.